# Shadow and border separate when using CSS translates

Tags: css, transform

When using both a border and a shadow on a single element that is absolutely positioned using a negative translate (the technique is explained [here](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)), I experience an odd rendering bug in Firefox and IE (it seems to work in Chrome).

When the element has an uneven size, the element is placed on a half pixel which (likely due different rounding) separates the shadow and the border from each other, revealing an ugly gap:

[image: Shadow (green) is separated from the border (blue)]

The example is available at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Auoeq), but you can also reproduce this by placing a div in a document, and using the following CSS:

```
body {
    background: black;
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 299px;
    height: 99px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px 20px springgreen;
    border: 10px solid deepskyblue;
}
```

Do you have any idea how to avoid this problem, how I can force the element to be placed on a full pixel? I tried adding `transform-style: preserve-3d` to the parent element, as suggested by the article, but that didn’t work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could only reproduce the bug in Internet Explorer 11 and edge. It seems to be working fine in FireFox and chrome (didn't test others such as Opera).

Note: the half pixel problems only occurs when the rendering region itself has an uneven size.

You might have found that out by yourself in the mean time, but for reference:
The only workaround I found is to use values that will be rounded to full pixels. Adding a `.1` to your uneven sized element will make it so it gets rounded to the closest higher even value so it will "snap" to the pixel in browsers that do not support true subpixel rendering while no visible change will occur on browsers supporting it since the difference in position will be of a 20th of pixel.

So the update code would be

```
div 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 299.1px;
    height: 99.1px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px 20px springgreen;
    border: 10px solid deepskyblue;
}
```

You can find a [code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aLapMX) demonstration of the problem and the fix I personally use.

Comment: Yeah, since I encountered that problem—three years ago o.O—it has since been fixed in Firefox. As for your `.1` fix, that’s actually a pretty nice workaround for this, nice :)

Comment: Yeah, I ran into the problem myself but on IE. Found a few hacks online but I think this one is the best and, since i saw that your post had no answer I thought it'd make sense to give it a lil' update and a work around for others :-)